# Google Cloud Armor: Cannot get the match expression to work for "in" operator and list ".exists"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

### 'in' operation

I have a list of origin asns that I would like to block access using CloudArmor. I am using the match expression and trying something very simple like this:

```
origin.asn in [12, 13]
```

I just cannot understand what the syntax is for `in`. I have reread this cel-spec language definition countless times and I can't figure out.
https://github.com/google/cel-spec/blob/master/doc/langdef.md#list-of-standard-definitions

The doc claims:

> Set membership test of a json number in a list of integers:
>
> json.number in [1, 2, 3]
>
> int(json.number) in [1, 2, 3]

So I wrote the following and it still gives me the syntax error. See screenshot:
[image]

I have pretty much gone through all the examples from google docs too, and they are very basic for me, and do not help. https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#expression-examples

### list ".exists" macro

The lang spec claims:

> e.all(x, p): tests whether a predicate holds for all elements of a list e or keys of a map e. Here x is a simple identifier to be used in p which binds to the element or key. The all() macro combines per-element predicate results with the "and" (&&) operator, so if any predicate evaluates to false, the macro evaluates to false, ignoring any errors from other predicates.
>
> e.exists(x, p): like the all() macro, but combines the predicate results with the "or" (||) operator.

Again, just doing a simple test with the `.exists` macro, I get the error. See screenshot:
[image]

I can only assume that I am missing something really basic or the lang spec isn't really supported at this current time by CA. I would be grateful if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this paragraph might mislead the readers. [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference).

> The custom rules language is used to write the expressions in advanced match conditions for security policy rules. The Google Cloud Armor custom rules language is an extension of the [Common Expression Language (CEL)](https://github.com/google/cel-spec).

Cloud Armor match expression probably does not implement all the lang definitions from the CEL-spec, hence the error. Best to rewrite these expression in to smaller and multiple rules.